# Django search query feature like Django admin or Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to figure out a proper way to make a search functionality for my model fields like Django's admin or Django rest framework's search feature.

Suppose I have this model, I would like to search through all the fields.:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=254,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
```

First, I tried this way:

```
user_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q(id__icontains=int(search_input)) |
    Q(email__icontains=search_input) |
    Q(first_name__icontains=search_input) |
    Q(last_name__icontains=search_input) |
    Q(mobile__icontains=int(search_input))
)
```

This works fine if I am filtering with only the integer search terms. However, if I pass a string value, this breaks and it gives me an error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

So now what I came up is something like this, to catch any Value errors and exclude integer searches from the filter:

```
try:
    user_list = User.objects.filter(
        Q(id__icontains=int(search_input)) |
        Q(email__icontains=search_input) |
        Q(first_name__icontains=search_input) |
        Q(last_name__icontains=search_input) |
        Q(mobile__icontains=int(search_input))
    )
except ValueError as e:
    user_list = User.objects.filter(
        Q(email__icontains=search_input) |
        Q(first_name__icontains=search_input) |
        Q(last_name__icontains=search_input) |
    )
```

I am hoping there's a better way then this. Or maybe a field look up feature that I am not aware of?

Comment: Just remove your `ìnt` conversion on your `mobile__icontains` lookup: it'll be handled by ORM.

Comment: @JulienKieffer Nice. And here I was, making things complicated! Thank you! You can answer the post and I will be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just remove `int` conversion on your `mobile__icontains` lookup: it'll be handled by ORM.

Answer (score 0):

For my project the number of fields were large so used an external package(django-filter) to handle the search the url to package is https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html